# Ubuntu 16.04 installation help on lenovo y510p

Tags: uefi, lenovo

I am  very confused as I'm new to Ubuntu and I have multiple guides suggesting different things for UEFI boot systems(some say disable to Legacy, some say its not required)

I have a lenovo y510p laptop , it came with Windows 8 pre-installed, I checked my boot system its UEFI. I have now upgraded to Windows 10 via windows update itself.

I wish to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside my Windows 10, can someone please link me to a proper guide for the same ? I can't risk losing my data and I don't have a backup drive , hence I need someone experienced to guide me. Any links would suffice too or just brief steps in the reply itself or on PM. I'm basically confused about do i need to disable UEFI and secure boot or not and also the fact how to proceed about the installation.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: By installing a new/second OS there is always the chance of loosing your data. Especially if you need to resize a partition to get space for the OS. **No one** can guarantee that nothing goes wrong. That's why you should **always make a backup**

Comment: Disable secure-boot at least temporary for the installation. Do not disable UEFI, if Windows is installed in UEFI-mode you have to install Ubuntu in UEFI-mode too. Use only Windows-tools to manage Windows-partitions in order to  gain space for Ubuntu before you install.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've already partitioned your drive, if not use the Windows Disk Manage tool (found by typing 'partition' in Start menu) or `diskpart` in command prompt. Info on how to create a partition [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/). (My preference is 40-60gb for a moderate use Ubuntu installation)

> do i need to disable UEFI

In your case **do not** disable UEFI because your Windows installation is installed as UEFI. If you boot Ubuntu in BIOS/Legacy, it will most likely not recognize your Windows installation and overwrite it. You want your OS's boot modes to match.

> secure boot or not

Current Ubuntu versions support Secure Boot, but it's not tested on all pre-built PC's. In the unlikely case that you encounter errors, you can disable it in the laptop UEFI with `F2` or `F11` immediately upon restarting. You can also go into the UEFI by clicking the restart button in the Start Menu while holding `shift`. Then go to `Troubleshoot/Advanced Options/Startup Settings` (may also be called `UEFI Firmware Settings`) .

As for installing Ubuntu, (assuming you're using a Live USB) change your boot order in the UEFI so that USB drive/media comes before your hard drive and boot manager. After that, boot onto the USB and follow the Ubuntu installer with the `Install alongside Windows Boot Manager` option.

*Note: I've encountered this issue on a few laptops, if the Live USB Ubuntu **doesn't boot into UEFI mode** you may need to try different USB ports on your laptop as some ports may only support BIOS booting and others allow UEFI.*

[For more info on Ubuntu and UEFI.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)